# Why is $\cos(\arctan(3x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 9x^2}}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why is $\cos(\arctan(3x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 9x^2}}$? I've tried messing around with identities but still I'm not sure what's going on here.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1894265/how-do-i-show-this-cos2-arctanx-frac11x2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either go for a trigonometic identity connecting $\tan$ with $\cos$; or:

**Hint**: in a right triangle, $\tan$ of an angle is equal to the ratio of the lengths of the opposite side to the adjacent side. For an angle $\theta = \arctan(3x)$, you have $\tan \theta = 3x$ so imagine such a triangle with opposite side $3x$ and adjacent side $1$.

What is the length of the hypotenuse (Pythagoras!)?

Then what is $\cos \theta$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan^2 u + 1 = \sec^2 u$$

Apply that to $u = \arctan(3x)$ to get
$$ (3x)^2 + 1 = \frac{1}{\cos^2 (\arctan(3x))}
$$
Now invert:
$$ \frac{1}{(3x)^2 + 1} = {\cos^2 (\arctan(3x))}
$$

and take a square root.

Answer (score 1):

If we use the well-known formula
$$\forall X\in \mathbb R$$
$$\cos^2(X)=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(X)}$$

with $$X=\arctan(3x),$$ we get

$$\cos^2(\arctan(3x))=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(\arctan(3x))}.$$

$$=\frac{1}{1+9x^2}$$

in the end, notice that

$$-\frac{\pi}{2}<\arctan(X)<\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$\cos(\arctan(X))>0.$$
thus

$$\cos(\arctan(3x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+9x^2}}.$$